# Smarty 3 template from outside templates folder

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have had been doing same with previous smarty versions... Like loading a TPL file outside of specified templates folder, like this:

```
$smarty->display("../admin/bin/tpl/default.tpl");
exit();
```

however since upgrade, I receive following errors:

```
[12-Jun-2013 11:40:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file '../admin/bin/header.tpl' in '../admin/bin/tpl/default.tpl'' in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried an absolute path? i.e.

```
$smarty->display("/var/www/mywebsite.com/templates/admin/bin/tpl/default.tpl");
```

That should work according to [the manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.display.tpl#id517262) (and it does for me)

Comment: Thank you! it works... how could I've not guessed it first? need a break lol

Comment: You can also define multiple paths for templates http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.template.dir.tpl